Connecting Rust with PostgreSQL on Docker
I created a compose.yml and a Dockerfile to connect Rust (Actix Web) with PostgreSQL (SQLx). Now, I am encountering some errors, and the compile error says the following:
DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:secret@postgres:5432/postgres

35.08 error: error communicating with database: could not resolve address `("postgres", 5432)`
35.08   --> src/controllers/game.rs:10:24
35.08    |
35.08 10 |       let query_result = sqlx::query_as!(
35.08    |  ________________________^
35.08 11 | |         Game,
35.08 12 | |         "SELECT * FROM m_game"
35.08 13 | |     )
35.08    | |_____^
35.08    |
35.08    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query_as` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info) 

DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/postgres

29.20 error: error communicating with database: Connection refused (os error 111)
29.20   --> src/controllers/game.rs:10:24
29.20    |
29.20 10 |       let query_result = sqlx::query_as!(
29.20    |  ________________________^
29.20 11 | |         Game,
29.20 12 | |         "SELECT * FROM m_game"
29.20 13 | |     )
29.20    | |_____^
29.20    |
29.20    = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::sqlx_macros::expand_query` which comes from the expansion of the macro `sqlx::query_as` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)     

The purpose of my project is to integrate a Rust backend with a Next.js frontend and PostgreSQL, with hopes of deploying the project on AWS or other cloud platforms.
Connecting Rust with PostgreSQL in a local environment is not my primary goal. I prefer to do this on AWS RDS, but debugging in a local environment is essential.

rust
  backend:
    container_name: backend-rust
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        DATABASE_URL: "${DATABASE_URL}"
    volumes:
      - .:/gamernage
    working_dir: /gamernage
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: "${DATABASE_URL}"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}"

postgres
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_USER: "${DATABASE_USER}"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    ports:
      - "${DATABASE_PORT}:${DATABASE_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - db-store:/var/lib/postgresql/data

Dockerfile
# Build stage
FROM rust:latest as builder

WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    clang \
    lld \
    libssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    build-essential

# Install sqlx-cli
RUN cargo install sqlx-cli

# Copy source codes and toml
COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
COPY src ./src
COPY migrations ./migrations
COPY .sqlx ./.sqlx

# Enable offline mode for sqlx
ENV SQLX_OFFLINE=true

# Save queries
RUN cargo sqlx prepare

# Final stage
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    libssl3 \
    ca-certificates \
    libclang-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy binary files built
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/gamernage /usr/local/bin/

# Command to execute
CMD ["gamernage"]


Do you have a Postgresql server running and configured on your local machine? sqlx can only connect to existing DB servers, not start them.

Yes, PostgreSQL server is running on a db container. I configured it in compose.yml file

Did you export the 5432 port from the container? Can you connect to the DB from a console (e.g. with psql postgres://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/postgres)?

Please [edit] your post to include a [mre].

I think I exported the port because I saw the port 5432 on my Docker Desktop. Updated my post above.

I tried to hit the command psql postgres://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/postgres but error occurred. psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: ユーザー"postgres"のパスワード認証に失敗しました. I mean, this is a "Authentication Failed"

But, I could connect to the DB as a superuser like entering psql postgres://postgres:root@localhost:5432/postgres

The problem is that the creation of the backend image runs before bringing the postgres service up, assuming you are using docker compose up.
In your case running docker compose up will:

Build the backend service image using the Dockerfile specified.
I assume your Dockerfile contains compiling of your Rust project. Since the postgres service is not started yet, it fails.

I think you have to use the offline mode of sqlx. cargo sqlx prepare saves query metadata to a .sqlx directory. It contains information about your DB schema, so it can type check your queries without connecting to a database. Be sure to have the DATABASE_URL not set during the compilation (building the backend service image), otherwise sqlx will try to connect to the database during compilation, giving you the same error.
More information here:
https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/blob/main/sqlx-cli/README.md#enable-building-in-offline-mode-with-query

I followed these steps below:


run postgres container with docker compose up postgres


comment out args: DATABASE_URL on a build section on a backend service


created a new dicretory ./sqlx and rewrote Dockerfile as:


Yet, compiler says "error: set DATABASE_URL to use query macros online, or run cargo sqlx prepare to update the query cache"

It's not possible to use the postgres service in your compose.yml for the build of the docker image for the backendservice.
So you have to use the offline mode of sqlx.
You have to run cargo sqlx prepare with a running and accessible postgres server containing the correct schema. This creates the metadata files used in the offline mode.
